# Merge columns using common same name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(text = c(0, 0, 0, 1), text.1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0), "text sth"=c(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

I would like to merge columns which have a word which is common between the name of each column. In the example this is the "text". The lengths of rows is equal and the dataframe doesn't contain NAs.

Example of expected output:

```
DF <- data.frame(text = c(1, 1, 0, 1))
```

Is there any way to make it?

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of "merge"? Is it an AND operator, sum, or something else?

Comment: How many variations of "text" are there? Are there 100s of words we are looking to match, or a low amount that we could type by hand?

Comment: One should define merge rules for`names(DF)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check, for every row, if it contains something else than a zero, right? Judging from the way you formulated the question, I assume that every row represents a word and every column a document, like in a [Term-Document Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) (TDM).

You can do this with `apply()` over the rows:

```
apply(DF, 1, function(x) !all(x == 0))*1
# [1] 1 1 0 1
```

Surely, in a full TDM you will *always* have at least one non-zero entry per row.

The remaining issue boils down to subsetting your TDM according to some rule:

```
rule1 <- grepl("text", names(DF))
subdf <- DF[, rule1]
apply(subdf, 1 function(x) !all(x==0))*1
# [1] 1 1 0 1
```

Note that I calculated `rule1` separately so that you can easily adapt that rule to your real data and/or more complex criteria.